# How do you scale a vector image to equal a measurement in inches?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, scale, laser-cutting

I need to send a vector file to a textile laser cutter. The image size is 521 pixels, and I'm hoping to create a motif that equals 18.75 inches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your paths, then in the Application bar, make sure "Constrain Width and Height Proportions" is enabled. Then, type in <kbd>18.75in</kbd> in the appropriate dimension field.

[image]

Comment: Great suggestion! I tried this and it solved the height and width problem, however it kept all the line point widths the same instead of increasing them proportionally. The motif is quite a few circles ("bubbles") that are now all freely floating around instead of being connected to each other. Is there a way to keep the proportions of the paths the same?

Comment: Btw thank you for the very helpful graphic, that probably saved me a few hours

Comment: the laser cutter wont care about line widths. Anyway theres an option in the transforms palettes menu for this.

Comment: @Julie Select all the stroked paths and use `Object > Expand Appearance` to turn the strokes into shapes. *Then* increase the size. I suspect you would need to do this anyway. As joojaa says, NC equipment will follow the path and ignore the width of the stroke unless strokes are converted to shapes.

Comment: Julie there's a preference in Illustrator that is disabled by default and I've never understood why: Scale Strokes and Effects. Enabling preference will cause the line width (strokes) to scale proportionately. Also, @joojaa is spot on about the cutter not caring about the line width.

Comment: typically the cutter will use line width to determine the laser setting tough. So follow the machine shops instructions. they might have etchong and cutting options. Havent done much laser cutting w illustrator tough, i use cad for manufacturing.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! I ended up calling the laser cutter, and then tracing around the circle motif of various path widths with the pen tool on a .25 width. (Wish I had checked this feed and tried what @AlanGilbertson suggested first, that seems like it would have been much faster!) Thanks again all, this is my first time using this site and it was incredibly helpful :)